# Eclipse problem in windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Hello I am getting the following error when trying to compile a c++ project under Eclipse Indigo in windows:

`mingw32-make all

'Building file: ../src/testing.cpp'

'Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler'

g++ -I"c:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.5.0\include\c++\tr1\" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/  testing.d" -MT"src/testing.d" -o "src/testing.o" "../src/testing.cpp"
g++: no input files

mingw32-make: *** [src/testing.o] Error 1`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Eclipse Indigo hasn't been released yet.  Does it work if you try it in Eclipse Helios?

Comment: I havent try that,i used indigo in linux,I thought it will work here too,I will try now with Helios

Answer (score 0):

There must be some extra spaces somewhere before the name of the file, because you have a very strange file name in the arguments:

```
-MF"src/  testing.d"
```

Should be

```
-MF"src/testing.d"
```

The wrong path somehow must break the compile line and `g++` doesn't understand what the input file is.